# ajax call loader url loads same div tag multiple time issue

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, jsp

Could you please help me in sorting this issue as im just learning ajax and trying to incorporate for my requirement.

My Requirement:

When i click a particular image it should call the same page but load with the table data with different values based on the param values called.So I was advised to go for AJAX as it doesnt reload the whole page .

JQUERY

```
    $("#goToCostTypeID").click(function () {
                 var costType = document.getElementById("costType").value;

                 if(costType == "Actual"){
                       costType = "Budget";
                       document.getElementById("costType").value = "Budget";

                 }  //if actuals ends
                 if(costType == "Budget"){
                       costType = "Forecast";
                       document.getElementById("costType").value = "Forecast";

                 }  //if actuals ends
                 if(costType == "Forecast"){
                       costType = "Actual";
                       document.getElementById("costType").value = "Actual";

                 }  //if actuals ends

                 var Budget = costType;                          

                  $.ajax({

                         dataType : "html",
                         url:'my.jsp?productID=6&appID=6&txtHidden=Costs&mode=Edit&costType='+costType,
                          type:'POST',
                         contentType :'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
                          data:{costType:Budget},
                          success:function(result){ 
                              console.log("YES");
                              $("#costContent").load('my.jsp?productID=6&appID=6&txtHidden=Costs&mode=Edit&costType='+costType);
                        }   
                   });


            });
```

HTML

```
     <td width="2%" id="goToCostTypeID">&nbsp;<a href="#" ><img src="../images/goto.png"/></a></td>

    <div id="costContent">   

    <td width="13%" ><input type="hidden" id="cost_type_<%=i+1 %>" name="cost_type_<%=i+1 %>[]" value="<%=Bean.getLevelTwoOrgId()%>"/><%=Bean.getCcLevel2()%></td>
     <td width="12%" ><input type="hidden" id="intival_<%=i+1 %>" name="intival_<%=i+1 %>[]" value="<%=Bean.getInitProj()%>"/><%=Bean.getInitProj()%></td>
```

JAVA

```
       String costType = request.getParameter("costType");

      uploadCostList =DAO.doGetAppCostUploadedList(PK_AppID,costType,iPresentYear);
```

Im getting the same table multiple time when I click the image. Please help me.

With Regards,
Saranya C

Comment: As far as I can see your conditional logic is broken at all. It will always return 'Actual'. I don't understand what this logic should do. I suggect you to try to remove these conditions and only call ajax with `document.getElementById("costType").value`

Comment: Hi dganenco,I want to change the text based on onclick like Actual,Budget or Forecast and Yes u are right now only Actual is getting invoked multiple time.

Comment: And how you want me to change the ajax call??Can you please explain?

Comment: First the page gets loaded with "Actual" data . When click the image it should load with Budget and so on.So I'm assigning the value like if its in Actual page and user clicks next value in text should be changed to "Budget" and load budget data

Comment: You may want to look at your logic again.  you are making an ajax call, which is a request to the server,  and when that completes, inside the success, you make ANOTHER request with the load call.  You should be able to use dganenco's example, or make use of the result data from your first ajax request.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can understand your requirements you need simply to do smth like this:

```
$("#goToCostTypeID").on('click', function() {
  const currentCostType = $('#cost_type').val();
  const nextCostType = currentCostType === 'Actual' ? 'Budget' : currentCostType === 'Budget' ? 'Forecast' : 'Actual';
  $('#cost_type').val(nextCostType)

  const url = 'my.jsp?' + $.param({
    productID: '68',
    appID: '68',
    txtHidden: 'Costs',
    mode: 'Edit',
    costType: $("#costType").val()
  });
  $("#costContent").load(url);
});
```

Comment: Hi dganenco, Thanks for the simplified change. But still issue remains the same.1)The table gets loaded twice and 2)Same Actual value gets passed. Please help me

Comment: Many Many Thanks dganenco and  ChrisThompson.

Comment: $('#costContent').remove();  after onclick function and   $("#costContent").load(url); after the URL framed . But removes the  whole table and doesnt load

Comment: Similar to `.empty()`, the `.remove()` method takes elements out of the DOM. Use `.remove()` when you want to remove the element itself, as well as everything inside it. In addition to the elements themselves, all bound events and jQuery data associated with the elements are removed. 

You can try `$('#costContent').html("");`

Comment: adis and dganenco Thanks a lot:):). Its working as expected. You both saved me:) Thanks